# Javascript Decimals

Tags: javascript, types, formatting, currency

How can I convert a integer type to a double/float type so it shows decimal points? For instance if I want to convert a number to a money format:

5 would turn into 5.00
4.3 would turn into 4.30

Does javascript have something I can use to do this kind of conversion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: the decimal 4.3 is identical to the decimal 4.30.  Are you wanting a formatted decimal or a formatted string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
var a = 5;
a.toFixed(2); // '5.00'
4.3.toFixed(2); // '4.30'
```

Comment: so there is not types in javascript? I can't convert to double or float?

Comment: parseFloat(string), would get you back to a Number, but no individual Number types like int, float, double, byte, etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toFixed(n)`, where `n` is the number of decimal places.

```
5 .toFixed(2);
//-> "5.00"

4.3 .toFixed(2);
//-> "4.30"
```

Comment: @IAbstract: I wouldn't really say that's relevant, since it would be a rare occasion where you would write it out like this.  Normally, you would call `toFixed()` on a variable, otherwise you may as well just write the number as a string literal in the first place.